# Linking if true statement in R

Tags: r

I have a set of data in R. 800 samples with 12 observations generated randomly between 10 and 20. From this, i have two options, if the random generated number is less than 15, then the selection is option one and above 15, its option B. Now i want to generated a set of data for option one from its mean and sd as the normal distribution where the option A is true.

```
Run1 <- replicate(800, rnorm(12, mean=16, sd=3.1))
```

Im not sure how to link my other piece of code that says whether the option A is TRUE and thus generate a value for Run1?

**edit**: i essentially currently have a matrix which comprises of TRUE and FALSE, for the arguments above (option A - mean=16, sd=3.1 and option B - mean=18, sd=3.3) where A is TRUE for values below 15 and FALSE for values above 15. so a matrix like this is derived (just a small sample of full matrix)

```
  [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]
```

[1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  [2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

So what i want now is two matrices (one for A and on for B) which provide a mean value where A is TRUE (matrix A) from a normal distribution of the option A values detailed above and a mean value for B where it is FALSE (matrix B) from a normal distribution of the option B values detailed above ideally posessing N/A or similar where the value should not be generated in the corresponding matrix.

and then finally i would also like to combine these two matrices to form a third final matrix. may seem labourious but its necessary.

Thanks

Comment: I don't quite get it. Do you want to generate 800 sets of 12 normal deviates with different choices of mean and sd for the two cases (A, `runifval<15` vs B, `runifval>=15`)?  If so, are {16,3.1} the choices for case A?  Can you tell us what the corresponding values would be for case B?

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much it. case b is 18 (mean) and  3.3 (sd) and like is said the key part is that obviously i only want a value to be generated as per the previous code whereby a value is present for A if it is TRUE and a value is present for B where it is FALSE.

Comment: do you mean of the 12 items chosen for each case?

Comment: Please see a further edit above.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to construct a matrix of the right size, then use row indexing to fill values into the appropriate rows ...

```
set.seed(101)
runifvals <- runif(800,10,20)
result <- matrix(nrow=800,ncol=12)
lowvals <- runifvals<=15
## sum(lowvals) is the number of rows of data we have to generate for case A ...
result[lowvals,]  <- rnorm(sum(lowvals)*12, 16,3.1)
result[!lowvals,] <- rnorm(sum(!lowvals)*12,18,3.3)
```

This assumes it's OK to have the result as an 800x12 matrix (but that's probably the most convenient format in general).

**edit** if you really want two separate matrices with embedded NAs (*this seems odd/wasteful, but whatever ...*):

```
matA <- matB <- matrix(NA,nrow=800,ncol=12)
matA[lowvals,]  <- rnorm(sum(lowvals)*12, 16,3.1)
matB[!lowvals,] <- rnorm(sum(!lowvals)*12,18,3.3)
```

Comment: Yes thats nice, i would prefer to have two different matrices, one for option A and one for B, what would you suggest is the most convenient way to do this?

Comment: I was nearly there, but im getting and unexpected error on this:    "Error: unexpected ',' in "matA <-matrix(sum(lowvals)*12,16,3.1),"              and yes i think the positional information will be very important, i was hoping to create a zero or N/A where a value was not created in order to maintain the matrix shape

Comment: yeah you are right it is a little odd right now but it has to feed into the next step im coding. As im sure you have realised im a complete novice in R at the moment but am learning quickly. Your above edit is pretty much what i was looking for only it gives matrix A as all N/A and B as the complete set :)

Comment: that's because I accidentally set the min value for `runifvals` to 15 rather than 10 ... see edited version above

Comment: thanks for your help, greatly appreciated. there appears to be something odd about the output as it follows a very distinct pattern, what i mean by this is that either an entire row has values or it is N/a for both options. This does not reflect the randomness of my earlier work.

Comment: OK, maybe I misunderstood your question -- that's what I thought you wanted.  Can you give a sample (by editing your question) of the first few rows of your desired output?